# Winning Streak Achievement in Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am currently implementing a multi-player game using Google Play Services. The game also uses the provided Achievement system which works very well. However, I am really struggling to implement some sort of "Winning Streak" achievement which should be unlocked if

> The user has won 5 multi-player games in a row.

In the developer console I have created an `Incremental Achievement` and set the needed steps to `5`.

In code I would like to implement the following concept:

- If the user wins the game, the achievement steps are incremented by 1.
- If the user loses the game, I would like to reset the achievement step counter.

If I understand the API correctly it is NOT possible to reset/decrement an achievement counter for non-testers. Therefore the only possibility to implement such an achievement would be, to store the current count of games won in a row locally on the device, alternatively in the cloud.

This is not a satisfactorily solution because:

1. The user will not see the current "progress" of the achievement in the achievement intent
2. It requires more effort to implement it this way, especially if the user plays on two different devices

I really would like to know if Google provides another possibility to implement such achievements than introducing some sort of temporary counter.

Comment: There will be no way except to track it locally - and using cloud save to sync the value between devices. There is no way to reset **any** achievements from the developer side once the Game Services are published. You could of course display this kind of "locally tracked" information on the win screen - ex. when the user has won a match display a message such as "2 matches won in a row" or whatever. This way, when they check the achievements screen they can know from the description how far they are towards reaching the goal. It's not ideal, but it is the best you can do.